# i need run function in component from page with data page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

i have a component for draw graph or tree and i use this component in the page.
my axios is on the page and give datas , i need pass datas to function of component and next draw my tree from data of page.

**My Page**

```
<template light>
  <v-app>
    <TreeComponent :treedata="treeData"/>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      treeData: {}
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get('url')
      .then(response => {
        this.treeData = response.data;
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

**My TreeComponent**

```
export default {
  props: {
    treedata: {
      type: Object
    },
  },
  methods: {
    drawTree(data){
      console.log("draw")
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.drawTree(this.treedata)
  },
}
```

Comment: your props/events flow looks correct, so what is the question

Comment: this not work. After receiving the information log does not work

Comment: your codes looking fine, have you tried testing it without the `v-app` component, just to see if that's blocking something or not?.

Comment: dont work. Also the output that shows me the value is undefined. The drawTree function does not run after receiving data from the server. the drawTree function run once in start with undefined value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mounting the TreeData component before the APIcall is finished, meaning the drawTree method runs while treeData is still undefined. Two options:

---

- If it needs to be drawn once, when the data is received, add `v-if="treeData"` to your component on the main page. This will only render it once your data has been returned from the server (when treeData is a truthy value).

**MainPage.vue**

```
<template light>
  <v-app>
    <TreeComponent v-if="treeData" :treedata="treeData"/>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      treeData: null  // empty object is truthy, so change to falsey value
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get('url')
      .then(response => {
        this.treeData = response.data;
      })
  }
}
```

---

- If it needs to be drawn again every time treeData changes, create a watcher:

**TreeComponent.vue**

```
export default {
  props: {
    treedata: {
      type: Object
    },
  },
  methods: {
    drawTree(data){
      console.log("draw", { data })
    }
  },
  watch: {
    treedata: {
      immediate: true,
      deep: true,
      handler(newV, oldV) {
        this.drawTree(newV)
      }
    },
  },
}
```