# How to call to sub component’s method in parent component Vue

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I want to run the sub component’s method from the parent component in vue to refresh some areas of that component. Here is an example of what I want.

***Home.vue***

```
<template>
   <componentp></componentp>
</template>

<script>
.....
methods:{
  parentMethod(){
    //I want to call to methodx in componentp
  }
}
...
</script>
```

***componentp.vue***

```
<template>
..............
</template>

<script>
....
methods:{
 methodx(){
   //Run me from parent
 }
}
}
...
</script>
```

I want to call methodx in sub component how can i do it.?

Comment: Move the update process to the parent and pass down the data to the child instead.

Comment: Check [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55317353/219933).

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot do what @Chris G says, another alternative could be to use a watcher:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Create some 'control' variable and watch if it changes to make your process.

Answer (score 1):

you can watch parent of parameter from component and run function in component after change parent parameter.
see this link.
[i need run function in component from page with data page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68378343/i-need-run-function-in-component-from-page-with-data-page)

Answer (score 1):

```
<template>
   <componentp ref="componentp"></componentp>
</template>

<script>
.....
methods:{
  parentMethod(){
    //I want to call to methodx in componentp
    this.$refs.componentp.methodx()
  }
}
...
</script>
```